# BeautifulSoup Returning "None" Eventhough the element exists

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the price of a product in amazon. But BeautifulSoup is returning "None". Assuming it would the problem with html.parser, I changed to lxml. But it didn't work. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

```
import requests 
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Inch-Internal-MZ-76E1T0B-AM/dp/B078DPCY3T"

headers = {"UserAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
product_name = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
product_price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()

print(product_name,"\n",product_price)
```

Comment: It works for me. Sometimes Amazon will block you. Maybe try using a `try` / `except`

Comment: okay. Let me try that

Comment: Nope. Still not working. It's scarpes the whole page. But doesn't individual elements

Comment: For example: It scrapes if you print the variable soup

Comment: amazon block some server IP, try `print(page.text)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the headers, you have written

> headers = {"**UserAgent**"...}

And it is written

> headers = {"**User-Agent**"...}

I think that that's the problem.

So the code would be like this:

```
import requests 
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Inch-Internal-MZ-76E1T0B-AM/dp/B078DPCY3T"

headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
product_name = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text().strip()
product_price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text().strip()

print(product_name)
print(product_price)
```